# API for usb encryption

Tags: java, usb

I am doing a project for college in which I am creating a website that will encrypt a file and decrypt a file.

Now I want to add functionality that will provide a function for selecting USB drive from an `HTML` form and will MAKE that USB password protected. I have no ideas. I searched a lot and I found many tutorials in `C#` and `C++` but I am not getting how will I do it on server.

Is there any java API that provides this functionality? I found: `jUSB`, but it does not seem to be helpful.

Comment: If I understand this correctly, I don't see how you can accomplish this server side.  Either you will need to push an applet with *very* significant access privileges to user's machine, or equivalent in another client-side (e.g. browser) language.

Comment: Define "MAKE that USB password protected".

Comment: Your question makes no sense.  Encrypting the contents of a drive (whether it's USB, SATA, IDE, SSD or anything else) is not a function you can accomplish from a browser/web page.  This is a case for a dedicated native program.

Answer (score 0):

One solution might be to use https, and then encrypt / decrypt on the server side.

You could also encrypt / decrypt using Javascript. Some example source code, using RC4 (just to get you started). But it is very tricky to get right, and I would argue you shouldn't do that, except if you really understand encryption, and there is no other way. Or, if you don't really care about security.

```
function encrypt(text, password) { 
    for(s=[], i=0; i<256; i++) s[i] = i; 
    for(j=0, len=password.length, t=0, i=0; i<256; i++) { 
        j = (j + s[i] + password.charCodeAt(i % len)) & 255;
        t = s[i]; s[i] = s[j]; s[j] = t; 
    } 
    for(j=0, i=0, len= text.length, x=0, r=[]; x<len; x++) {
        i = (i + 1) & 255; j = (j + s[i]) & 255; t = s[i]; s[i] = s[j]; s[j] = t; 
        r.push(String.fromCharCode(s[(s[i]+s[j]) & 255] ^ text.charCodeAt (x))); 
    } 
    return r.join(''); 
}
```

Comment: OK I give up. I have no idea what the question is about.